# How to auto-update local maven repository .m2 folder for offline build

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I am working on a large project which has lots of dependencies and many of them are SNAPSHOT dependencies. And because of snapshot dependencies, build takes a huge amount of time (around an hour) as for each dependency it needs to check if it is updated in the remote artifactory or not, even if the snapshot version is not changed. With release versions, there is no problem as only if the version is updated then only remote is checked else locally available jars from .m2 is used.

Compared to the above scenario, if I do offline build with -o flag when I have all the dependencies available in my local .m2, the build takes only about 5-10 minutes, which saves around 40-45 minutes of build time. But as the project is large and many people are working on it, whenever I pull changes, there may be some code-changes which requires the latest snapshot and offline build breaks as even a single mismatch can cause build break.

So to solve this, I am thinking about the following approach :
 1. Always build offline using -o flag.
 2. Create some external script (probably in nodejs), which will periodically keep scanning if dependecies given in pom is updated on the remote artifactory. If yes, pull into local .m2, else do nothing.

Is there any better alternative to this ? 
Also once I figure out which artifact to update, what is the way using which I can force update only that particular artifact without transitive dependencies?
With above approach, there is still chance of build break if any transitive dependencies are changed, but that would not happen frequently, and I would have to run full online build in that case.

I thought about setting up local proxy artifactory server, but it won't help in this scenario as for snapshot resolution it would any way go to the remote repository. If I keep cache time longer there is again chances of loosing changes and build break.

Comment: This is strange. If downloading the dependencies takes 45 minutes, there is something very wrong. Even in bad cases, some minutes should suffice. Either you have thousands of dependencies (which would be bad) or you have a terrible internet connection.

Comment: Considered running a local Maven repository in docker and let that handle the updating?

Answer (score 1):

You can control snapshots checking:

> Download policy
>
> updatePolicy  String  The frequency for downloading updates - can be
>   "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never"
>   (only if it doesn't exist locally).

https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-settings/settings.html#class_snapshots

But probably you have some other issue, since 45 mins for build wasted on downloading artifacts is a lot.

Comment: I am already doing this but this doesn't solve the main issue. If the update interval does not reach build is probably using an out-dated snapshot, possibly causing the build failure. or during build it will spend a lot of time to check if an artifactory server has an updated snapshot. That's the reason I want offline build.

Comment: if you absolutely need a super recent 'snapshot' version of external libraries, then there is no solution - maven should download them each time. But typically people keep 'snapshot' versions for at least a day, thats enough for daily builds.